# Как понять, открытое ли апи у сайта?

Tags: веб-программирование, api, request

Есть сайт, например, этот - https://azimo.com/en .

как вообще понять открытое ли у него апи? просто гуглить типа `azimo` и если что-то нахожу, то открытое, а если нет - то нет.

Какие рекомендации есть? Потому что в этом деле я новичок.

Использовать буду на `python/django`.

Comment: `просто гуглить типа azimo и если что-то нахожу, то открытое, а если нет - то нет.` - для начала, разберитесь что такое api. Потом подобные вопросы отпадут

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В подобных случаях самый лучший способ или почитать документацию на сайте, или задать прямой вопрос в техподдержку.

> просто гуглить типа azimo и если что-то нахожу, то открытое, а если
>   нет - то нет.

Находка в гугле ещё ничего не значит. Использование API (если оно есть) определяется лицензией, а не гуглом.

Как-то так...